# Electron's shell.openExternal opens a new window in internet explorer

Tags: push-notification, onclick, electron

I am using shell.openExternal(url) method in my push notifications electron app. Onclick of the  received push notifications,a new window opens in internet explorer but I want the same to be opened in Chrome.Is it possible?

Comment: If the app is running on your system you can change the default browser to be Chrome on your os. Open Chrome it should ask you for it.

Comment: I do not want to customize the settings on OS.Any methods or anything that I can mention in the code so that it defaults to Chrome?@JeffProd

Answer (score 0):

You can use Child process :

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('/usr/bin/chromium-browser https://example.com', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
        }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    });
```

But you must know on which OS you are to give the correct browser executable path.
The previous code works on Linux.

Comment: Executing `start chrome "example.com"` as a command would be the way to do it from Windows 7 +

Comment: BTW, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the code you provided didn't work but changing the command to `google-chrome https://example.com` worked.

Comment: Yes, `chromium-browser` must be installed : `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Answer (score 0):

shell.openExternal(url) will open the link in the System Default Browser. Hence, if you want to open it in Chrome, then make it as the default Browser.